# Cult of the Lamb missing general building after maxing out everything else

Tags: cult-of-the-lamb

I've levelled up everything but I have no idea how to unlock this final general building. [image]

Comment: the symbol somewhat resembles the grave symbol as seen on the wiki: https://cult-of-the-lamb.fandom.com/wiki/Grave  No clue how to unlock it though - I don't have the game

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's The Grave missing in your buildings. It can be unlocked in the Level 4 Afterlife Doctrine by choosing "Grieve the Fallen".

If you instead chose "Return to the Earth", it unlocks the Natural Burial building. So, you cannot unlock all buildings in a playthrough.

Comment: Ahhh! I was hoping that was my ticket to unlocking the remainder of the general follower skins. Thank you!